# Does StartUp-Manager work in 11.10?

Tags: boot, grub2, startup

Does StartUp-Manager work with Ubuntu 11.10 64bit?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get it to work but there is a brilliant alternative already mentioned by Juan in Grub Customizer for anyone looking for a GUI to edit boot and grub.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Comment: that's a really nice tool

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. It will let you edit `grub` but that's about it.

As of 10.04 Ubuntu doesn't use USplash or Splashy, it can't edit those configurations.

Comment: But Grub customizer cannot configure Plymouth!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work properly here. It ignores my default startup entry and always uses the above one. pretty annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Here too.. don't work properly. I set as default windows 7 and  every time boot with ubuntu. Now i try to use grub customizer. If i make it work i tell you, meanwhile you could try it too: http://shuffleos.com/2811/grub-customizer-customize-grub2-burg-settings/

Answer (score 0):

Startup manager doesn't work on my machines with Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit.

Grub Customizer, suggested by bimsebasse, works great even in Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

I've just installed grub-customizer and moved the windows xp component of the grub to the top (very top) of the list, then 'saved it'.  It worked perfect for me.

Give it another go, it could just be figure trouble.